# Apex assert vs assertEquals

Tags: apex

Hello here goes my question,

according to SFDC documentation "Case Sensitivity - To avoid confusion with case-insensitive SOQL and SOSL queries, **Apex is also case-insensitive**"

now if i do a `System.assert('a' == 'A');` Everything works just fine but,

if i do a `System.assertEquals('a', 'A');` I get an exception:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: a, Actual: A

checked System Methods and well assertEquals says "Asserts that the first two arguments, x and y, are the same. If they are not, a fatal error is returned that causes code execution to halt."

now if Apex is case insensitive shouldn't `System.assertEquals('a', 'A');` be true and not cause the error?

please advise if i misread something.

Sergio

Comment: Not your core question, but `System.assertEquals` is the one to use by default because on failures it reports the expected and actual values and that can help you fix a test failure more quickly than the data-less failure message of `System.assert`.

Comment: Hello @keith-c, thank you for the tip :) i'll take that into consideration, the only reason i posted the question was because i was following the apex quickstart guide and decided to change the examples a bit after i read they said it was case insensitivity but not long ago i had a case sensitivity error with a different example when i typed the case incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Apex itself is case insensitive, it seems that some (possibly all?) standard method calls are case sensitive.. here's another discussion that came to the same conclusion: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008vcnIAA. This article confirms Apex is "usually" not case sensitive (but more in regards to **c**lass vs **C**lass): https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex.

Comment: You've misread that line. *Compared to Java*, Apex Code is not generally case sensitive. This is why "a" == "A" and schema.account.class == Schema.Account.class (here, meaning I wrote Schema vs schema, but it resolved to the same class). The few exceptions to this are things like assertEquals, which is coincidentally case sensitive. I'm actually fairly sure that assertEquals is implemented as `(expected == null && actual == null) || (expected != null && actual != null && expected.hashCode() == actual.hashCode())` (or possibly `expected.equals(actual)`) instead of simply `(actual == expected)`.

Comment: I meant that... it was a typo on my end. Thanks! Editing..

Answer (score 6):

The `assertEquals` method is case sensitive, but if you use the '==' operator that is case insensitive per the Salesforce documentation on [Expression Operators](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm).

The first assertion could also be written as: `system.assert('a'.equalsIgnoreCase('A'));`

Comment: Personally, I hate String.equalsIgnoreCase, because it is functionally identical to ==. The presence of this function suggests that == is the same as Object.equals, which is *not* true.