# test class for trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
trigger updatepipelineamountField on Opportunity (after update) {

Map<Id,Decimal>  budgetIDTotalMap = new MAp<Id,Decimal>();  
set<id> setbudgetId = new set<Id>();

for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
{
    if( opp.budget__c != null){
        setbudgetId.add(opp.budget__c);
    }
}

for(AggregateResult objArg : [SELECT budget__c, SUM(Amount) total FROM Opportunity WHERE budget__c IN: setbudgetId AND (stageName = 'Prospecting' OR stageName = 'Value Proposition')  GROUP BY budget__c])
{
    budgetIDTotalMap.put((Id)objArg.get('budget__c'), (Decimal)objArg.get('total'));
}
List<Budget__c> blist = [select id,Pipeline_Amount__c from budget__c where id in :setbudgetId];
for(Budget__c c: blist)
{
    c.Pipeline_Amount__c = budgetIDTotalMap.containskey(c.id) ? budgetIDTotalMap.get(c.id) : 0;
}
update blist; 
}
```

and I wrote a test class for this but I am getting error:

```
@isTest
private class TestupdatepipelineamountField {

@isTest static void TestupdatepipelineamountField() {
    // Test data setup
    // Create an account with an opportunity, and then try to delete it
    Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account');
    insert acct;
    acct=[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:acct.Id];
    System.assertEquals(acct.Name,'TestOpp');

    Budget__c bud = new Budget__c(Name ='Jan', Budget_Amount__c = 10000, Won_Amount__c = 5000, 
                                  Commit_Amount__c = 2000, Best_Case_Amount__c = 1000, 
                                  Pipeline_Amount__c = 1000)
    insert bud;

    bud=[SELECT Name FROM Budget__c WHERE Id=:bud.Id];
    System.assertEquals(bud.Name,'Jan');

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name=acct.Name + ' Opportunity',
                                   StageName='Prospecting',budget__c = bud.Name
                                   CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                                   AccountId=acct.Id);
    insert opp;
    opp=[SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:opp.Id];
    System.assertEquals(opp.Name,'TestOpp');


}
}
```

Error: unexpected token: 'insert' at line 14 column 8
can any one help me to figure out the error and let me know where I am wrong.
@Ratan

Comment: `budget__c = bud.Name
                                   CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),` you forgot one `,` here  it should be like `budget__c = bud.Name, CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),`

Comment: I put (,) now I am getting error : unexpected token: 'insert' at line 15 column 8

Comment: This topic has already been discussed and answered. [Apex assert vs assertEquals](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/apex-assert-vs-assertequals/58685)

Comment: Still getting the same error after change the Account name. @Ratan

Comment: @Russelbaker1 What does your tigger do? I just want to confirm I understand what your trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO many errors.. SO I am writing complete code..

```
@isTest 
private class TestupdatepipelineamountField { 

    @isTest static void TestupdatepipelineamountField() { 
        // Test data setup 
        // Create an account with an opportunity, and then try to delete it 
        Account acct = new Account(Name='Test1'); 
        insert acct; 
        acct=[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:acct.Id]; 

        Budget__c bud = new Budget__c(Name ='Jan', Budget_Amount__c = 10000, Won_Amount__c = 5000, 
        Commit_Amount__c = 2000, Best_Case_Amount__c = 1000, Pipeline_Amount__c = 1000); 
        insert bud; 

        bud=[SELECT Id, Name FROM Budget__c WHERE Id=:bud.Id]; 

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name= acct.Name + ' Opportunity', StageName='Prospecting', budget__c = bud.Id, 
                                            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1), AccountId=acct.Id); 
        insert opp; 

        opp=[SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:opp.Id]; 
        System.assertEquals(opp.Name,'Test1 Opportunity'); 

        opp.StageName = 'Value Proposition';

        update opp;

        system.assertEquals([SELECT Budget_Amount__c FROM Budget__c WHERE Id =: bud.Id ].Budget_Amount__c, 10000);

    } 
}
```

Comment: Test fail with Error:  Assertion fail: Test account, actual: testopp

Comment: @Russelbaker1 what is expected result ?

Comment: Test is fail. I saw in developer console so it is showing error: String Exception :Invalid id: Jan  Line 20 column 1

Comment: There is no point in your first 3 asserts. You're inserting objects and asserting their names (which you just inserted)... are you just testing DML there? The last assert is good :)

Answer (score 0):

In the test class , you are not closing a line with ';'

```
Budget__c bud = new Budget__c(Name ='Jan', Budget_Amount__c = 10000, Won_Amount__c = 5000, 
                                  Commit_Amount__c = 2000, Best_Case_Amount__c = 1000, 
                                  Pipeline_Amount__c = 1000);
```